# Why is React Native AsyncStorage so slow on my phone?

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I have a problem with an App im Developping with Expo - React Native. The problem is that, having only one small value stored in **AsyncStorage**, its **takes around 25 seconds** to load. There are the details:

`Expo`: Version 33

`Ract Native (comes with Expo)`: 0.59.8

`My stored values`: {keyOne: "ValueOne"}

This is only an example for testing, obviously in the actual app i have more values. The code i am using for testing, inside `App.js` is:

```js
async componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Storing value...");
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("keyOne", "valueOne");
    console.log("Value stored");
    var value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("keyOne");
    console.log("Obtained value: "+value1);
}
```

With this code, the `25 seconds` are spend storing the item.

I'm facing this problem **specifically in Samsung Phones**, for example a `Galaxy S7 SM-g930F`. This happens when developing and in production app.

Also, if I store more values, the first that i obtain is the one slow, the rest are very fast.

Another detail is that, if i make the same test with **SecureStore, is very fast**. 
Can i do something to speed things up?
Some alternative to AsyncStorage?

Comment: Good one. I found a really good article here which has some recommendation to optimize performance 

https://medium.com/@Sendbird/extreme-optimization-of-asyncstorage-in-react-native-b2a1e0107b34

Comment: @Rigorousimplementation I have come across that article. But the problems i have are **with only one key stored**. So them dont appear to be optimization problems.

Comment: Can you test your problem in expo  snack: https://snack.expo.io/@emanuelenardi/async-storage try to change the sdk versions, will you get the same performance issue 33-35.

Comment: Have you figured a way to make AsyncStorage fetch faster? Even at the end of 2020, it's still slow

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure to do following.**

1. Upgrade react-native version to 0.59.5 +
2. Don't import {AsyncStorage} from react-native (as it is deprecated now)
3. Use this package instead [Async Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage)
4. Import like this **import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';**

Comment: Hi, i am using Expo with React Native. So **i can't use Community Async-Storage** because of the inability to Link. I tried to use it with no luck. Besides, i read that the **library is essentially the same** but React Native have externalized it.